# date_default_timezone_set() Broken timezones

Tags: php

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
    $time = date("H:i a");
    $hour = date("H");
?> 
<?php if($hour >=6 && $hour <12){?>
    <body class="morning">
        <div id="txt1"><h1 id='time'><?= $time?></h1></div>
        <div id='dayMessage'>Good Morning</div>
<?php } elseif($hour >= 12 && $hour <18){?>
    <body class="afternoon">
        <div id="txt1"><h1 id='time'><?= $time?></h1></div>
        <div id='dayMessage'>Good Afternoon</div>
<?php } elseif($hour >= 18 && $hour <0){?>
    <body class="evening">
        <div id="txt1"><h1 id='time'><?= $time?></h1></div>
        <div id='dayMessage'>Good Evening</div>
<?php } elseif($hour >= 0 && $hour <6){?>
    <body class="night">
        <div id="txt1"><h1 id='time'><?= $time?></h1></div>
        <div id='dayMessage'>Good Night</div>
<?php }?>
```

Running this code using European timezones it returns a blank page whereas using `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` Returns a background and the time.
Does this mean there is something wrong with my installation or are some of the timezones just broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition makes no sense:

```
else if($hour >= 18 && $hour <0) ...
```

there is no number that is smaller than `0` and at the same time also bigger than `18`.. if you want to represent the slot `[18-24]`, just une the `>= 18`:

```
else if($hour >= 18) ...
```